# How to serialize JSON java.util.Date variable to ISO-8601 format date string in WildFly?

Tags: json, jboss, jackson, resteasy, wildfly

I am using WildFly 8.0.0 Final. The rest WebService implementation is RestEasy. According to the WildFly/Jboss documentation, I have added jboss-deployment-structure.xml to use Jackson2.2.* provider.

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <exclusions>
           <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jackson-provider"/>
        </exclusions>
        <dependencies>
            <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jackson2-provider" services="import"/>
        </dependencies>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Right now, my problem is that all the java.util.Date variables are not serialize as ISO-8601 format. I have seen this post [Wildfly using the Jackson provider instead of Jettison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19502878/wildfly-using-the-jackson-provider-instead-of-jettison) , but it's using jackson-provider-1.

Is there any configuration that can make all date variables be formatted as ISO-8601?

I don't want to add any outside dependencies. Only using WildFly provided is the best choice. I have add the below dependency into my pom.xml file. My code is at https://github.com/evil850209/javaee7-samples

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

I have done the something as this post ([Wildfly using the Jackson provider instead of Jettison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19502878/wildfly-using-the-jackson-provider-instead-of-jettison)) mentioned. Now I got new error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper
    at org.chris.demo.rest.JacksonConfig.<init>(JacksonConfig.java:18)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ConstructorInjectorImpl.construct(ConstructorInjectorImpl.java:148)
```

I have changed my jboss-deployment-structure.xml, and I put it under WEB-INF folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <exclusions>
            <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jackson-provider" />
        </exclusions>
        <dependencies>
            <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jackson2-provider" services="import" />
            <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.jackson-jaxrs-json-provider" />
        </dependencies>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

My JacksonConfig class is like:

```
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.ContextResolver;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature;

@Provider
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class JacksonConfig implements ContextResolver<ObjectMapper> {

    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    public JacksonConfig() {
        objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);
    }

    @Override
    public ObjectMapper getContext(Class<?> type) {
        return objectMapper;
    }

}
```

It seems like the jboss-deployment-structure.xml is not import the jackson2 class to my WildFly server. Is there anyone how to resolve this issue?